# TIme - SQL (Minutes and Seconds)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a TIME table. This table has two columns: one for minutes and another one for seconds. I made their datatype as a Decimal.

Is there a way to create a derivative column where minutes and seconds are in this format mm:ss from my two columns?

IF NOT, How do I insert data into my minute column if its not a DECIMAL type? What type should it be?

Thank you!

Note I am using SQL server

Comment: Why not use the built in `time` column type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments make it sound like you're trying to do arithmetic on intervals (or durations).

SQL Server's `time` data type "Defines a time of a day. The time is without time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock." You can't add two `time` values; 2 o'clock + 3 o'clock is literally nonsense. In SQL Server 2012 . . .

```
select cast('2:00' as time) + cast('3:00' as time)
Operand data type time is invalid for add operator.
```

Other dbms might return a nonsensical number.

Standard SQL includes a data type called `interval`, which supports the arithmetic and formatting you'd expect. So 2 o'clock + 3 hours would return 5:00:00 (5 o'clock). In the absence of support for the `interval` data type, store the most granular unit (seconds, for you) as an integer, and format it yourself for display. I might use a view, myself.

```
declare @val as integer;
-- 10:01:12, 10 hours, 1 minute, 12 seconds, in seconds.
set @val = (10 * 60 * 60) + (1 * 60) + 12;

-- Leading zeroes for minutes and seconds.
select @val as total_sec, 
       concat(@val / (60 * 60), ':', format((@val / 60) % 60, 'D2'), ':', format(@val % 60, 'D2')) as total_time
```

```
total_sec  total_time
--
36072      10:01:12
```

Answer (score 0):

As @mclaassen pointed out, I'd be curious why you aren't using the built in `time` data type.

That said, if you really want to build a time table by hand, then you can have a calculated column.  Let's call it `timeString`.

```
alter table [time] 
    add timeString as (left('0' + cast([minutes] as varchar(10)), 2) + ':' + left('0' + cast([seconds] as varchar(10)), 2))
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx for documentation on calculated columns in SQL Server.